# How to install Neo4j on CENTOS 6.7 x86_64?

Tags: centos

I want to use Neo4j on CENTOS 6.7 x86_64, but I could not set up the Neo4j Server, I am using secure shell, typing this command :

```
wget -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | apt-key add -
```

gives me this error:

```
apt-key: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are following a guide written for debian based distributions, give a try to a guide for RHEL based distros, eg.: http://distributedbytes.timojo.com/2015/05/how-to-install-neo4j-server-on.html

Note: I've not tested it